# Counting list levels based on string identifiers - multi-leveled lists

Tags: excel

Similar to my last post, I am working through counting the number of levels in a multi-level list. The goal output is to fill out columns G:I (there are more, but this is illustrative).

```
  A      B        C        D         E          F            G          H       I
+------+------+--------+---------+----------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
| L1   | L2   |   L3   |   L4    |   L5     |   L6       | L4_count | L5_c  | L6_c  |
+------+------+--------+---------+----------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
| 1    | 1.1  | 1.1.1  | 1.1.1.1 |1.1.1.1.1 | N/A        |   2      |   2   |   0   |
| 1    | 1.1  | 1.1.1  | 1.1.1.1 |1.1.1.1.2 |1.1.1.1.2.1 |   2      |   2   |   2   |
| 1    | 1.1  | 1.1.1  | 1.1.1.1 |1.1.1.1.2 |1.1.1.1.2.2 |   2      |   2   |   1   |
| 1    | 1.1  | 1.1.1  | 1.1.1.2 |1.1.1.2.1 |1.1.1.2.1.1 |   2      |   1   |   1   |
| 1    | 1.1  | 1.1.2  | 1.1.1.2 |N/A       |N/A         |   2      |   0   |   0   |
+------+------+--------+---------+----------+------------+----------+-------+-------+
```

My solution so far has to been to thus:

```
={MAXIFS(IFERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(E:E)),0),IFERROR(VALUE(MID(E:E,9,1)),0),VALUE(MID(E2,9,1)))}
```

Attempting to find the max last digit if the second to last digit is the same as the reference cell. However, I keep getting a "there is a problem with your formula". Any help would be appreciated, very open to restructuring the table. Thanks!

Comment: you can't do operations on the data in maxifs.  It wants ranges not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in G2:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(IF(MID(D$2:D$6,LEN(D$2:D$6)-2,1)=MID(D2,LEN(D2)-2,1),--RIGHT(D$2:D$6))),0)
```

Use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to exit edit mode.  Then copy over and down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly then you can use following formula in cell `G2`.

`=MAX(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(D$2:D$6,C2&".","")+0,0))`

Copy down and across as much as needed.

Please note that this is an array formula and therefore needs to be committed by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> simultaneously. If done correctly then Excel will wrap the formula with braces {}.